# How to enable option 6 in "SKT" Package

Tags: xetex

Page 4 of the below link says that I have to enable "option 6" to use Sanskrit Transliteration of  RgVeda.

- http://mirrors.ctan.org/language/sanskrit/sktdoc.ps

Can anyone help me out in enabling the "option 6". I don't know how to enable it :(

Comment: According to section "Dynamic Option Selection", you should do `{\skt [6+] ...}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Options can be specified with the syntax

```
{\skt [6+] ...}
```

According to the documentation in section "Dynamic Option Selection", the options thus set remain *globally* active, so they should be disabled by

```
[6-]
```

in the same or in a later `\skt` group. So

```
{\skt [6+] <text 1> [6-] <text 2> }
```

will apply option 6 only to `<text 1>`. Alternatively, use

```
{\skt [6+] <text 1>} {\skt [6-] <text 2> }
```

which should give the same result.